# Xcode build error "Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1" in simulator and real environment

Tags: ios, xcode, build, compiler-errors, ios-simulator

I recently created a new project. It was 8 months ago when I created the project last time. So, when I built a new project with simulator, I got an error like the following.

```
CodeSign {app directory}
cd {app directory}
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity:     "-"

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --entitlements /Users/{username}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{app directory}
/Users/{username}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{app directory}/{app name}: Is a directory
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I tried

- Confirm Xcode sign-in status
- Check Automatically manage signing
- Clean up and delete build DerivedData
- Reboot Xcode and PC
- Reinstall Podfile and cocoapod
- Recreate certificate
- xattr -c

I tried several method. But it did not solve it.
Most people seem to be OK in a simulation environment, but in my case it is not. Both the real environment and the simulation will not work.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error is there in the output from the command:

/Users/{username}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{app directory}/{app name}: Is a directory

You most likely have some custom build phase or script phase which is stomping over your app's executable with a directory.

Comment: Thank you. However, I do not remember changing the build method since I created the project. In addition, this error occurred once before. Could you tell me how to investigate the cause of this error, if possible?